# sudo: command not found jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, configuration, sudo

I am using bash script in Jenkins pipeline that connects to another machine and perform sudo command there:

```
script.sh '''
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ${DEPLOYMENT_KEY} deployment@${MACHINE_IP} sudo rm -rf /tmp/${FOLDER} | true
'''
```

the job failed with this error message:
sudo: command not found.

how can I debug the issue, I can perform a sudo command in the machine, is there any configuration that I need to check in the machine?
Thanks!

Comment: Log in manually to `deployment@${MACHINE_IP}` and check if you can run `sudo`. Is the t `| true` intentional? This will hide both the output and the exit code of the `ssh` command. I don't know what `true` does with `stdin`. Depending on its implementation, piping data to it might result in blocking a program that sends more data than the pipe buffer can hold.

Comment: @Bodo I logged to the machine and run the commands manually and it worked

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Please copy&paste the command and the output (if any). As a next step run the `ssh` command manually and show the command and its output. Please copy&paste the complete error message from jenkins.